# How To get twitter friends list in iphone

Tags: iphone, twitter

I am using Twitter API for my iPhone app,and i want to get my twitter friends list,i followed the older posts but not getting the answer,any one please help me out...

```
(NSString *)getFollowersIncludingCurrentStatus:(BOOL)flag{
  NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]init];
  str =[_engine getFollowersIncludingCurrentStatus:YES];
  NSLog(@" string is %@ ",str);
}
-(void)userInfoReceived:(NSArray *)userInfo forRequest:(NSString *)connectionIdentifier {
  NSArray *mFollowerArray = nil;
  mFollowerArray = [userInfo retain];
  NSLog(@"mfollwers arra is %@",mFollowerArray);
}
```

Comment: @polynomial getFollowersIncludingCurrentStatus:(BOOL)flag  i used this method,but i am unable to get the list

Comment: Please post your code. People can't help you if they don't know what you're doing.

Comment: @prasanna : you should edit your question rather than putting your code as comment.

Answer (score -1):

First thing is that twitter is having followers and not friends. check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6660228/twitter-followers-in-iphone-sdk-in-self-account) link. You might get a direction for your search. Thanks.